# Tool - site that shows grid overlay?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, tools

Quick question - Does anyone know of a site where you can type in a url of someone else's site, and the site will show a grid overlay, or somehow show the grid system that that url uses? I could have sworn that there was something out there like that, but for the life of me I can't remember it. Google turns up nothing, but perhaps I'm just not finding the right phrase to ask. Orrrr...maybe I'm just crazy and the site doesn't exist.

Comment: This question asks for [shopping recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and is off-topic for all StackExchange sites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't sorry. Most of the grid frameworks have a .showgrid class. I'm assuming that if you know the framework's name you can use the browser Dev Tools to show it.

Comment: [This](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42791/19473) should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Carefully reading Lara's question would have brought to your attention that she mostly needs a way to show the grid system name, which is what the html/css panel of the Dev Tools gives you. My post allows her to do so and also to learn a bit more about the tools she's going to need.